# How to round up the values to 1 decimal place using google sheet query?

Tags: google-sheets, bar-chart, rounding

[image]

Hi everyone,

I have a set of raw data, I use query function in cell `C2` to order and count the raw data. May I know how to include the `ROUND` function in the `QUERY` so that the output in column C will be only 1 decimal place. The reason I'm doing this is to reduce the number of bars in the bar chart. As you can see in the chart, 50.79 and 50.8 are considered as 2 bars, but it will be more presentable if I combine them together by rounding up 50.79

*Preferably doing the rounding in `QUERY` instead of creating another column

This is my spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12enDKh4hDE67XyvA-21_0CeVxNojzMmNWGjRZfCFmQE/edit#gid=0

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added two sheets ("Erik Help" and "Erik Help 2").

Yours is a case where pre-processing the `QUERY` data will be beneficial. Note that doing so creates a virtual array that is no longer able to be referenced by column letter; rather, *Colx* notation is required in the `Select` clause.

The formula in "Erik Help" produces exactly the results you requested in your post:

`=query(FILTER(ROUND(A2:A,1),A2:A<>""),"select Col1, count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 order by Col1 asc label Col1 'Values', count(Col1) 'Count'")`

The formula in "Erik Help 2" refines the data by rounding every number in A3:A to the nearest `0.5` (which you could change to `0.2` or `0.25` or whatever you like). You can use this option depending on how discrete you need your results to be:

`=query(FILTER(MROUND(A2:A,0.5),A2:A<>""),"select Col1, count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 order by Col1 asc label Col1 'Values', count(Col1) 'Count'")`